# Какое правило о кавычках здесь используется?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении — *Он использовал слово «правильный»* — последнее слово нужно заключать в кавычки. Это понятно. Но каким правилом это требование регулируется? Это можно считать разновидностью цитаты?

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный пример подпадает под это правило.

**Кавычками выделяются:**

> слова из чужого текста, цитаты: Правда, некогда правильные и теперь ещё приятные черты лица его немного изменились, щёки повисли, частые морщины лучеобразно расположились около глаз,  **«иных зубов уж нет»,**  как сказал Саади, по уверению Пушкина (Т.); …Воспитанный на красивом языке бабушки и деда, я вначале не понимал такие соединения несоединимых слов, как  **«ужасно смешно», «до смерти хочу есть», «страшно весело»…** (М.Г.); Он  требовал пересмотреть работу —  **«поскольку я внёс нужные исправления»**  — и заново оценить её; Достаточно было бы одной просьбы —  **«помогите мне выпутаться из создавшегося положения»,**  — и всё пошло бы по-другому; Он сказал про себя  **«подумаешь!»**  и пошёл дальше; Именно эти действия они называли  **«взаимопомощь»;**  Он сказал не  **«глупый», а «недальновидный»**

[Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь.](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827548.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B17%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%C2%A758%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: А если слово в кавычках не "чужое" (напр.: Я употреблю слово "правильный"), как это подпадает под правило?

Comment: @Alex_ander, см.:http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=141#pp141 пар. 153.

Comment: Я не нахожу там определения для случая, под который подпадает  "слово такое-то" (видовое наименование понятия "слово" + само слово)..

Comment: Alex_ander, там говорится о грамматической необычности. Т.е. слово употребляется не как обычная гр. единица. А как самостоятельная.